# What I can conclude from this graph Bayesian, Euclidean and mahalanobis classifier?

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, matlab, euclidean

I have solved this problem:

> Generate a set of data of N = 1000 2-dimensional vectors that stem from three equiprobable classes. The three classes are modeled by Gaussian distribution with means $ \mu1 =|1, 1|^T$, $ \mu2 =|12,8|^T$, $ \mu3 =|16, 1|^T$ and their covariance matrices are S1 = S2 = S3 = 4I, where I is the identity matrix 2X2.
>
> 1. Use the Euclidean distance classifier to classify the points of X1 based on the ML estimates computed before.
> 2. Use the Mahalanobis distance classifier to classify the points of X1 based on the ML estimates computed before.
> 3. Use the Bayesian classifier to classify the points of X1 based on the ML estimates computed before.

I did it in MATLAB with the toolbox from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123744865) and I get:

- Bayesian error: 0.0240
- Euclidean error: 0.0230
- mahalanobis error: 0.0230

and this graph:

[image]

I do not know how to conclude based on my data and graph, can someone please guide me? (I know the red points are the 1 class, the green points are the 2 class and the blue points are the 3 class.)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung please help

Comment: Your question is vague. Since you have computed error I can only assume that you have proper labels for each of the clusters. That said, replot the data to determine which of the data points was wrongfully classified. I would venture to say most of the error came from the closeness between the green and blue clusters.